# Why is it justified to move the limit into the exponent?

Tags: limits, exponentiation

On my last math test my teacher told me that my notation for evaluating limits "might be problematic." The notation he is referring to is when evaluating a limit of the form $$\lim_{x\to \infty}{f(x)}^{g(x)}$$
What I usually do is write it as $$\exp(\,\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)\ln f(x)\,)$$
He would like me to write 
$$y=\lim_{x\to \infty}{f(x)}^{g(x)} \\
\ln y=\lim_{x\to \infty}{g(x)}\ln{f(x)}$$
They are essentially the same process, so why would my method be problematic? If there is nothing wrong with it, then how can I justify it to him? Specifically, how can I rigorously justify transferring the limit to the exponent? i.e. $$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{f(x)}=\exp (\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x))$$

Comment: Well.  if $\lim g(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim e^{g(x)} = 0$ is another but $e^{\lim g(x)} = e^{-\infty}$ is "possibly problematic".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The property you need for $\lim_{x\to c}f(g(x))=f(\lim_{x\to c}g(x))$ to hold is for $f(x)$ to be continuous. This is either the definition of $f$ being a continuous function, or equivalent to the definition (some people use that the inverse image maps open sets to open sets). Since $e^x$ is continuous, you're fine.

Comment: @Sky: That is the defining property of continuous functions (at least, as far as real-valued functions of real numbers are concerned).

Comment: Some people define continuity to be the property of a function such that every open image under it has an open preimage (even in $\mathbb{R}$).  But the two definitions/properties can be shown to be equivalent.

Comment: Mmmm.... I have a bit of a problem with $e^{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}} = e^{\infty}$ vs. $\lim e^n$.

Comment: @fleablood what do you mean? both $\lim e^n$ and $e^{\lim n}$ are unbounded

Comment: Okay $e^{\lim -n}$ .  $e^{\infty}$ or $e^{-\infty}$ make me *very* uneasy.

Comment: Why would that make you uneasy? That's not even a well defined term in standard analysis. It's obvious that $e^x$ is continuous, right?